# Database refusing to update via AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

I try to avoid asking for help when sorting out a programming problem but right now I'm stumped and could do with some input from you good people.

**The Scenario:**

I have a page on a site that I'm developing that  allows certain users to select locations on a Google map as locations for visits all of the updating is done via ajax to a mySQL database all of which works fine. 
When the users have finished selecting they press a button that locks the selection process for the current year, this is done simply by doing an AJAX database update to a flag bit on the visitors table called Selection_Complete.

**The problem:**

Up until a few days ago everything seemed fine however I then noticed that the selections weren't being locked when the finish selection button was pressed, which is odd given it had worked before some looking around revealed that the database flag had stopped updating.

Here's the code concerned:

The JavaScript close function:

```
function closeSelection() {

var conf = confirm('Are you sure you want to finish selection ?');

if (conf === true){

    setCompletionStatus(userID,1,function(data){

        if (data === -1) {
            displayMessage ('Unable to close selection: an error occurred in update');
            console.error('setCompletionStatus() returned -1 a database error occoured during query');
            return;
        } else if (data === -2) {
            displayMessage ('Unable to close selection: an error occurred in update');
            console.error('setCompletionStatus() returned -2 a database error occurred during query');
            return;
        } else if (data === 0) {
            displayMessage ('Unable to close selection: an error occurred in update');
            console.error('Close selection returned 0 update enabled, should have been 1 to close');
            return;
        } else if (data === 1) {
            selectionComplete = data; // a global variable holding the current users selection status
            lockSelectBtns();
            displayMessage('Selection now closed for ' + dateInfo.getFullYear());
            $('#placementMessages').html('Selection closed for ' + dateInfo.getFullYear()).css({
                'color':'red' 
            }).show();
            return;
        } else {
              displayMessage ('Unable to lock selection: an error occurred in update');
              console.error('Unknown code: ' + data + ' returned by setCompletionStatus()' );
        } 
    },displayMessage);   
   }
 }
```

The javaScript  Ajax handler:

```
    function setCompletionStatus (userID,isComplete,callback,failCallback) {
    if ((! jQuery.type(userID)=== 'String') && (! jQuery.type(userID)=== 'number')) {
        throw new Error ('The userID parameter of function  setNumChoices() (AJAX) was of type '+ jQuery.type(userID) +
            '\n either a String or an Integer was expected.');
    }
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            mode: 'setIsComplete',
            userID: userID,
            isComplete:isComplete
        }
    }).fail(function(jqHXR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
        console.error('An error occurred while calling setCompletionStatus() \n response text was: ' + jqHXR.responseText + 
            + ' \n status was: ' +  textStatus + '\n' + 'Header contents was: ' + errorThrown);

    }).done(function(data){
        if ( (typeof data === 'undefined')||(typeof data === 'null')) {
           failCallback ('Unable to set completion status');
            console.error('An error occurred while calling setCompletionStatus.done() data was null or undefined');
        }
        else  {
                callback(data);
        }   
      });
  }
```

And the PHP db query code:

```
public function setSelectionStatus($userID, $selectionComplete, $asJSON = TRUE) {try {
        $queryString = 'UPDATE Visitor 
                        SET Selection_Complete = :selectionComplete 
                        WHERE User_ID = :userID';

        $statementHandle = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($queryString);
        $statementHandle->bindValue(':selectionComplete', $selectionComplete);
        $statementHandle->bindValue(':userID', $userID);
         $success = $statementHandle->execute();
        $numRecords = $statementHandle->rowCount();

        if ( $success === false) {
            if ($asJSON) {
                echo json_encode(-1);
            }
            return -1;
        }
        else if ($numRecords === 0) {
            if ($asJSON) {
                echo json_encode(-2);
            }
            return -2;
        } else {
            if ($asJSON) {
                echo json_encode((int) $selectionComplete);
            }
            return (int) $selectionComplete;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Sorry,an error occurred while attempting update the current users selection status,administrators please check error logs for more details. <br/>' . PHP_EOL;

        error_log('An error occurred while attempting to run the query function' . __FUNCTION__ . ' of class ' . __CLASS__ . ' on server (' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
                . ')' . PHP_EOL . 'Details:' . PHP_EOL .
                'Message: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL .
                'In file: ' . $e->getFile() . PHP_EOL .
                'On line: ' . $e->getLine() . PHP_EOL .
                'Stack trace:' . PHP_EOL . $e->getTraceAsString() . PHP_EOL, 0);
    }
}
```

The AJAX function returns the correct value when setting the database field no errors are recorded in the logs neither the PDO or the PDO statement is returning any errors also I've checked the data being sent back and forth via firebug and that's and yet the database is refusing point blank to update the field.
I'm pretty sure its something to do with the AJAX call cos if I just run the PHP directly it works perfectly every time.
Sorry it a bit of a long one, can any one help? I've been looking at it for almost a day now and I'm at a loss.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you think there’s a difference in a “normal” call and an AJAX call, then log all relevant parameters to a file or something, and compare them for both cases.